# Using cat() to sum multiple vector elements

Tags: r, vector, sum, concatenation

I was working on a small R exercise on DataCamp, and the question was to generate 2 vectors of different sequences, and then use cat() and sum() to get the total sum of all elements of the 2 vectors.

```
seq1 <- seq(1, 500, 3)
seq2 <- seq(1200, 900, -7)
```

Option 1 works:

```
sum(seq1)
sum(seq2)
sum(sum(seq1), sum(seq2))
```

Option 2:

```
cat(seq1, seq2)
```

works, but I'm wondering why the following does not work:

```
sum(cat(seq1, seq2))
```

If `sum(seq1)` works, why doesn't summing up `cat(seq1, seq2)`, which is a vector of the 2 individual vectors combined? What is the right way to do this using the `cat()` function?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure they said `cat()`? Or did they mean `c()` (combine)?

Answer (score 1):

This may be the point of your exercise, but look at

```
res <- cat(seq1, seq2)
```

`res`  will be `NULL`

The point here is that there are (at least) two places for information to go when executing a function. There is what is displayed on your console and what is returned by the function. When you pass one function to another function, as in `sum(cat(...))`,  the function on the outside takes as input the value returned by the function on the inside. `cat()` returns `NULL`, but has a side effect of sending information to the console, so when you run `sum(cat(seq1, seq2))`, you'll get the sequence on the console, and then the result of `sum(NULL)`.

`c()`, as compared to `cat()`, actually returns the concatenated sequence. You can see the difference by passing `seq1` and `seq2` to both.

With `cat()`, the sequence is printed to the console:

```
cat(seq1, seq2)
# 1 4 7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34 37...
```

With `c()` the sequence is returned. It still goes to the console since you haven't assigned it to anything, but it looks different:

```
c(seq1, seq2)
#  [1]    1    4    7   10   13 ...
```

And, looking at the sum, with `c()` you just get the result:

```
sum(c(seq1, seq2))
# [1] 87029
```

With `cat()` the console is overtaken with the printed sequence, and then the result appears, which is `0`.

```
sum(cat(seq1, seq2))
# 1 4 7 10 13 16 19 22...
# ... 934 927 920 913 906[1] 0
```